Deciding between publishing a single or multiple papers
What are criteria that help to decide whether to publish several losely related results in a single publication that contains the results as "chapters" or each result in a separate publication?
The concrete case would be new results related to matching theory; some results would be concerned with the theory itself and others with new heuristics related to the TSP.

What does "TSP" mean?

@JochenGlueck, TSP stands for Traveling Salesman Problem and is about the abstraction of finding the shortest roundtrip through a set of  cities

Minor piece of advice: in the US, university administration is becoming increasingly more hostile to the interests of faculty. Faculty are being denied tenure or having tenure revoked due to not publishing enough. I think that, where possible, multiple papers is better for your career.

Publishing a single paper can be easier since it only has to go through review etc once. But having multiple stories in one paper makes it harder to clearly present each story, starting with choosing which one to emphasize in the title.

IMHO it depends on how closely the parts are related. There are two basic principles that sometimes are in conflict with each other:

Present one idea a time.

Put everything that is based on the same idea together.


Both are presumed to facilitate the reading and understanding of your work, and that (making the life of the reader as easy as possible and using his/her time as efficiently as possible) should (again, IMHO) be the primary concern when making the decisions when, what, and how to publish. Everything else is secondary.
As to "scooping" Buffy mentioned, my God, I wish (sincerely, no joke) that somebody would scoop me on some of my projects and take the headache of figuring out how to organize the exposition and endless proofreading off my shoulders. Fat chance! Showing your ideas (or even ready proofs) to other people has its benefits, of course: for instance, you understand better what you are talking about yourself after such discussions, but convincing somebody to seriously think of them usually takes more effort than finishing the project off by yourself.
Just my two cents :-)

thanks for sharing your thoughts on the issue; I think I will have to weigh the arguments and then take a decision. As I am not associated with a research institution and closer to ending a career than to starting, one, my importance ranking of arguments will likely differ slightly from what is reasonable under other circumstances.

Let's assume that all of the "chapters" are actually publishable, which isn't a given by any means.
You would be dealing with two different sorts of publishers for the two options. Some publishers will publish only single papers of some maximum length. Others, including book publishers, will publish longer works, sometimes as special issues. But the criteria for that are quite high.
However, as I see it, the main issue is timing. If you hold back publishing the early parts until the later parts are complete you stand the risk of getting scooped as it is common for several people/groups to be working on and thinking about the same ideas simultaneously. That its an effect of the "state of the art". People are intrigued and want to follow up recent work.
Ultimately, however, unless you intend to self publish, in which case your audience is likely to be small, the decisions are made by others. And, if you publish a lot of papers on the same general topic it is possible that later in your career there is room for a retrospective, bringing the ideas together.
I suggest that, unless you have something truly unique and remarkable, that individual paper is probably the best path. It also avoids the "all or nothing" possibility.
